# Why can't I use an enum as key in a interface with other keys

Tags: typescript

I found out via other issues *how* to make it work, but I couldn't find out WHY.

I have an `enum` I want to use as an object key in an interface:

```
export enum actions {
  insert = 'insert',
  merge = 'merge',
  assign = 'assign',
}
```

This Config interface of mine works:

```
interface Config {
  calls: {
    reads: storeName[]
    writes: storeName[]
  } & {
    [action in actions]?: storeName[]
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
interface Config {
  calls: {
    reads: storeName[]
    writes: storeName[]
    [action in actions]?: storeName[]
  }
}
```

It gives errors:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
>   A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

- `{ reads: storeName[], writes: storeName[] }` is a normal [interface type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html),
- `{ [action in actions]?: storeName[] }` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types),

And you can't write something that is both; though you can take an intersection of one of each.